# Different behavior of __weak on NSURL and NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Whats the difference between NSString and NSURL on __weak ?

My example:

```
__weak NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/tmp"];
__weak NSString *myString = @"123";

NSLog(@"myURL: %@", myURL);
NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);
```

**The result:**

> 2012-07-10 19:23:49.858 myApp[56093:303] myURL: (null)
>
> 2012-07-10 19:23:49.859 myApp[56093:303] myString: 123

Why isn't the result myString == (null)

Comment: I put the same code in main function and it's printing the values...

Answer (score 6):

This is because the string in your example is a **string literal** that *never* gets released. 
Your property doesn't retain the string but since it doesn't get released it still points to the value you assigned it.

If you would have created the string using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];` then you would see the expected behavior.

Comment: Strictly, `[NSStrign stringWithFormat:@"hello"];` might still return the literal string, but the principle of what you're saying is sound -- with a long enough format string you'll get a new, non-immortal object.

Comment: there is difference between having null and pointing to released memory.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: One of the fancy bits of ARC is that it automatically sets weak references to `nil` when the object is released. That's what happened here.

Comment: Yeah I know that, that's why I was thinking that it should have null instead of reference to string object.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

NSLog(@"myURL: %@", [myURL description]);

NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);

As "%@" is used to represent NSString not NSURL.

Comment: `NSLog()` sends `description` to the object of a `%@` format string. There's no need to send it manually -- `%@` works for any Cocoa object.